# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.mapview.AddLocation

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to display some message on `ondouble tap`.But i got his error.can anyone help me to clear this?Eror is posted below along with my code

**Java Code:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(AddLocation.this, (android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener) this);
    gestureScanner.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener(){ 
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) { 
                Toast.makeText(AddLocation.this, "DOUBLE TAP DETECTED!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 return false; 
            } 
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) { 

                 return false; 
            } 
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) { 
                 //viewA.setText("-" + "onSingleTapConfirmed" + "-"); 
                 return false; 
            } 


     });
```

can anyone help me rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not an instance of `android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`

Where do you use the cast statement in an inner class ?

Comment: And is your activity a OnGestureListener ? I guess no. Create an inner class for your OnGestureListener and instanciate it, and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of your GestureDetector. An alternative, less clean, is to make your activity implement the interface OnGestureListener